# Friction during circular motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, free-body-diagram, centripetal-force

Friction on a speeding bicycle (moving right to left) acts as:
[image]

Then how does the frictional force act as the centripetal force on a bicycle in circular motion?

...instead of something like this:
[image]

How will the FBD of both the tyres look like?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does friction play the role of centripetal force during the turning of a car?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/138871/)

Comment: I don't understand what causes the front wheel to rotate if all of the friction is directed towards the centre.

Comment: Not all of the friction is directed towards the center. Friction has one component towards the center as well as one against the direction of motion of the tire.